# Average pairwise correlations of an increasing number of variables (R)

Tags: r, correlation

I have a matrix called "variables" which includes 9 variables (9 columns). I have obtained the pairwise correlation matrix with this code:

```
matrix.cor <- cor(variables, method="kendall", use="pairwise")
```

Now I want to obtain the average pairwise correlation as a function of the number of variables considered. I mean, The average of all possible correlation of 2 variables, 3 variables, 4 variables... up to the 9 variables in order to see the effect of adding variables. I have this R code (extracted from an article which more factors and columns) but it does not run well, I only obtain the average considering the 9 variables.

```
pairwisecor.df = ddply(data,c("Exp"),function(x) {
Smax = unique(x$Rich)
x = x[,variables]
cormat = cor(t(x),use="complete.obs",method=c("kendall"))
data.frame(
Smax = Smax,
no.fn = nrow(x),
avg.cor = mean(cormat[lower.tri(cormat)]) ) } )
```

I think it couldn't be very difficult to create a function to analyze a cumulative number of variables... but I only have the reference of an article where the data is much more complicated.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fictitious example on calculating mean values among the increasing size of lower triangle matrices, starting from left upper corner:

```
> (cormat <- matrix((1:25)/25, 5, 5))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.04 0.24 0.44 0.64 0.84
[2,] 0.08 0.28 0.48 0.68 0.88
[3,] 0.12 0.32 0.52 0.72 0.92
[4,] 0.16 0.36 0.56 0.76 0.96
[5,] 0.20 0.40 0.60 0.80 1.00
> avg.cor = c()
> for (i in 2:dim(cormat)[1]) {
+   avg.cor=cbind(avg.cor,mean(cormat[1:i,1:i][lower.tri(cormat[1:i,1:i])]))
+ }
> avg.cor
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3] [,4]
[1,] 0.08 0.1733333 0.2666667 0.36
```